# How to extract the href attribute of an element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape the URLs within the HTML of the 'Racing-Next to Go' section of [www.tab.com.au](http://www.tab.com.au).

Here is an excerpt of the HTML:

```
<a ng-href="/racing/2020-07-31/MACKAY/MAC/R/8" href="/racing/2020-07-31/MACKAY/MAC/R/8"><i ng-
```

All I want to scrape is the last bit of that HTML which is a link, so:

```
/racing/2020-07-31/MACKAY/MAC/R/8
```

I have tried to find the element by using xpath, but I can't get the URL I need.

My code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Harrison Pollock\Downloads\Python\geckodriver-v0.27.0-win64\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.tab.com.au/')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ui-view/main/div[1]/ui-view/version[2]/div/section/section/section/race-list/ul/li[1]/a')
for e in elements:
    print(e.text)
```

Comment: You can try a split on you variable like string.split('"')[3]

Comment: Please post your code trial?

Comment: _I have tried to find the element by using xpath, but I can't get the URL I need._ What happens instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probaly you want to use `get_attribute` insted of `.text`. Documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute).

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ui-view/main/div[1]/ui-view/version[2]/div/section/section/section/race-list/ul/li[1]/a')
for e in elements:
    print(e.get_attribute("href"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use *getAttribute(attributeLocator)* function for your requirement.

```
selenium.getAttribute(//xpath@href);
```

Specify the Xpath of the element for which you require to know the class of.

Answer (score 1):

The value `/racing/2020-07-31/MACKAY/MAC/R/8` within the HTML is the value of `href` attribute but not the `innerText`.

---

### Solution

Instead of using the *text* attribute you need to use `get_attribute("href")` and the effective lines of code will be:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/ui-view/main/div[1]/ui-view/version[2]/div/section/section/section/race-list/ul/li[1]/a')
for e in elements:
    print(e.get_attribute("href"))
```